# Index 150 out of bounds in axis0 with size 1

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

I was making histogram using numpy array in Python with open cv. The code is as follows:

```
#finding histogram of an image

import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("cr7.jpg")
gry_img=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
a=np.zeros((1,256),dtype=np.uint8)

#finding how many times a particular pixel intensity repeats
for x in range (0,183): #size of gray_img is (184,275)
    for y in range (0,274):
        g=gry_ img[x,y]
        a[g]=a[g]+1

print(a)
```

Error is as follows:

> IndexError: index 150 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't supplied the image, it is only from guessing that it seems you've made a mistake with the dimensions of the image.   Alternatively the issue is entirely with the shape of your results array `a`.

The code you have is rather fragile, and here is a cleaner way to interact with images.  I use an image from opencv's data directory: [aero1.jpg](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/data/aero1.jpg).
The code here resolves both potential issues identified above, whichever one it was:

```
fname = 'aero1.jpg'
im = cv2.imread(fname)
gry_img = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

gry_img.shape
>>> (480, 640)
# note that the image is 640pix wide by 480 tall; 
# the numpy array shows the number of rows first.
# rows are in y / columns are in x

# NOTE the results array `a` need only be 1-dimensional, not 2d (1x256)
a=np.zeros((256, ), dtype=np.uint8)

# iterating over all pixels, whatever the shape of the image.
height, width = gry_img.shape
for x in xrange(width):
    for y in xrange(height):
        g = gry_img[y, x] # NOTE y, x not x, y
        a[g] += 1
```

But note that you could also achieve this easily with a numpy function `np.histogram` ([docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html)), with slightly careful handling of the bin edges.

```
histb, bin_edges = np.histogram(gry_img.reshape(-1), bins=xrange(0, 257)) 
# check that we arrived at the same result as iterating manually:
(a == histb).all() 
>>> True
```